# The subgraph induced by the neighbourhood of a vertex

Tags: graph-theory, connectedness, graph-connectivity, locally-connected

I have the connected graph as in picture 1 attached.

[image: Picture 1]

Is it correct if I take the subgraph induced by the neighbourhood of the vertex "a" as in the picture 2 below?

[image: Picture 2]

The neighbouring vertices of "a" are the vertices circled in red, right?

And the induced subgraph in Picture 2 is a connected graph right?

Can someone please help me with this question.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Normally the subgraph induced by a set of vertices means those vertices and all edges between them that were in the original graph.

So in your case it would be the four red vertices and the one edge between the topmost two of them.

There is also sometimes a distinction between "open neibourhood" (all vertices adjacent to $a$) and "closed neibourhood" (all those and also $a$).

Comment: Thanks a lot. Then in an open neighbourhood only the vertices adjacent to "a" and the edges between them which were in the original graph will be present? Without "a"?

Comment: @BuddhiniAngelika That is the most standard way to understand it, yes.

Comment: And in the closed neighbourhood when we have "a" then do we take the edges between the adjacent vertices and "a" as well to the induced subgraph?

Comment: @BuddhiniAngelika Once you fix a vertex set then "induced" means take all edges that were between them, so yes. In particular the subgraph induced by the closed neibhood of a is always connected.

Comment: Thanks a lot @MichalAdamaszek. There is a thorem, particularly theorem 1 in this document.https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/81191533.pdf . In that in the paragraph above theorem 1 they have defined about locally connected graphs by thinking about the induced subgraphs of the neighbourhood.

Comment: Do you know whether they are talking about the closed neighbourhood?

Comment: @BuddhiniAngelika They mean open. Otherwise it would not be very interesting.

Comment: Ok, yes, Thank you very much @MichalAdamaszek